# Ajax Modal Popup not closing on TextChange event in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events, modalpopup

In my page, I have a text_change event that is fired and it goes to the database, looks up a value, then sets textbox and hidden field.  After those fields are set, I display modal popup to validate the values returned.  The issue is once the popup is displayed, it takes about 30 seconds before the close button is active.  I have narrowed it down to the text_change event because I have several text_change events on the page which show a modal popup for validation and I get the same behavior for all of them.  I do not get the same behavior when I trigger the validation summary on the page from a button_click event  I am not sure why there is a delay and how to get past this issue.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/SiteMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="PoReceiving.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChatWirelessWebOLPApp.PoReceiving" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="page-heading" colspan="3" style="height: 20px;">
                        PO Receiving
                        <hr style="width: 99%; margin: 5px 0 10px 5px; padding: 0; background-color: #000;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="dvBody" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin: -24px 0 0 0; padding: 0;">
                <div style="width: 950px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; font-family: Calibri; font-size: small;">
                    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin: 30px 0 0 0; display: block;" id="Div2">
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin: -25px 0 0 0; display: block;" id="dvRo">
                        <div id="dv_RmaInfo" style="width: 950px; margin: 10px auto 0 auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                            <table style="width: 90%;" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="height: 30px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" CssClass="ErrorMsg" />
                                    </td>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblpallet" runat="server" Width="150px" Text="Pallet Nbr: " Style="margin-right: 5px;"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPalletId" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPkNbr" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ErrorMessage="Pallet Nbr Required" ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtPalletId"
                                                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="100px" Style="width: 100px;
                                                padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; background: #0071bd; border: 1px solid #ccc;
                                                color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup1"
                                TargetControlID="HiddenField1" OkControlID="btnDlgOK1" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopUp"
                                DropShadow="true">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup1" runat="server" CssClass="popUp" Width="300px">
                                <br />
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:ValidationSummary HeaderText="The following errors occurred:" ID="ValidationSummary1"
                                                ValidationGroup="group1" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium" Visible="true"
                                                runat="server" ForeColor="Black" align="left" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPopUpMsg1" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnDlgOK1" CssClass="button" runat="server" Style="width: 100px;
                                                padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px; background: #0071bd;
                                                border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;" Text="Close" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                        <%--<br />
<br />--%>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            <br />
                            <div id="Div3" style="width: 950px; margin: 10px auto 0 auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Shopping Cart:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtShoppingCart" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtShoppingCart"
                                                runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Shopping Cart Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtShoppingCart" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Enter Ship to Code:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipToCode" runat="server" Width="65px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtShipToCode_TextChanged" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                                ID="rfvtxtShipToCode" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Ship Code Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtShipToCode" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarket" runat="server" Enable="false" Width="250px" />
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLocId" runat="server" />
                                            <%--<asp:DropDownList
                                                ID="ddlMarket" runat="server" Visible="false" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtMarket"
                                                runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Select a Market" InitialValue="none"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="ddlMarket" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Customer Part Nbr/Mfg Part Nbr:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartNbr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtPartNbr_TextChanged" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                                ID="rfvtxtPartNbr" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Part Nbr Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtPartNbr" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right" valign="top">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Mfg Part Nbr:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMfgPartNbr" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right" valign="top">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label11" runat="server" Text="Serialized:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialized" runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="46px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right" valign="top">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label10" runat="server" Text="Part Description:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Enabled="false" Height="51px" Width="257px"
                                                TextMode="MultiLine" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="rowSerialized" runat="server" visible="false">
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label12" runat="server" Text="TMO Asset Nbr:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssetNbr" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtAssetNbr"
                                                runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="T-Mobile Asset Tag Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtAssetNbr" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label13" runat="server" Text="Serial Nbr:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialNbr" runat="server" Width="102px" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                                ID="rfvTxtSerialNbr" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Serial Nbr Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtSerialNbr" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label17" runat="server" Text="Putaway Bin:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBin1" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="rowNonSerialized" runat="server" visible="false">
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label14" runat="server" Text="Quantity:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtQty_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtQty"
                                                runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Quantity Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtQty" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label16" runat="server" Text="Putaway Bin:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBin2" runat="server" Width="97px" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label15" runat="server" Text="Nbr of Labels:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNbrOfLabels" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtNbrOfLabels"
                                                runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="Number of labels to print Required"
                                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtNbrOfLabels" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label18" runat="server" Text="Clear Shopping Cart:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCloseShoppingCart" runat="server">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="NO" Value="no" />
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="yes" />                                                
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="label19" runat="server" Text="Clear Pallet:" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClosePallet" runat="server">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="NO" Value="no" />
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="yes" />                                                
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6" align="center">
                                        <br />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Style="width: 100px;
                                                padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px; background: #0071bd;
                                                border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <asp:Button
                                                    ID="btnReset" Style="width: 100px; padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer;
                                                    margin-left: 5px; height: 23px; background: #0071bd; border: 1px solid #ccc;
                                                    color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;" runat="server" Text="Reset"
                                                    OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>



            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
                            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup2"
                                TargetControlID="HiddenField2" OkControlID="btnDlgOK2" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopUp"
                                DropShadow="true">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup2" runat="server" CssClass="popUp" Width="300px">
                                <br />
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:ValidationSummary HeaderText="The following errors occurred:" ID="ValidationSummary2"
                                                ValidationGroup="group2" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium" Visible="true"
                                                runat="server" ForeColor="Black" align="left" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPopUpMsg2" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnDlgOK2" CssClass="button" runat="server" Style="width: 100px;
                                                padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px; background: #0071bd;
                                                border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;" Text="Close" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>


                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" />
                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender3" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup3" TargetControlID="HiddenField3"
                                    BackgroundCssClass="modalPopUp" DropShadow="true">
                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup3" runat="server" CssClass="popUp" Width="300px">
                                    <br />
                                    <table align="center">
                                        <tr><td align="center">
                <asp:ValidationSummary HeaderText="Form Validation:" ID="ValidationSummary3" ValidationGroup = "group2"
                                    Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium"  Visible="true" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" align="left"/>                                   
            </td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPopUpMsg3" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                            </td> </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDlgOK3" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnDlgOK3_Click"
                                                        Style="width: 100px; padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px;
                                                        background: #0071bd; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; font-family: Arial;
                                                        font-size: 12px;" Text="Continue" />
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDlgCancel3" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnDlgCancel3_Click"
                                                        Style="width: 100px; padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px;
                                                        background: #0071bd; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; font-family: Arial;
                                                        font-size: 12px;" Text="Cancel" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <br />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                         </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="printConfirm" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" id="printString" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" id="nbrLabels" runat="server" />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="BusyIndicator" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="progress">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>





  protected void txtShipToCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtShipToCode.Text != "" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtShipToCode.Text))
        {
            PoReceivingDBHandler po = new PoReceivingDBHandler();
            DataTable location = new DataTable();
            string msg = string.Empty;

            if (!po.GetShipToLocation(txtShipToCode.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), ref location, ref msg))
            {
                ErrorLogging log = new ErrorLogging();
                log.LogError("PoReceiving.aspx.cs-txtShipToCode_TextChanged", "DB ERror", string.Empty, string.Empty, msg, HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginID"].ToString());
                ValidationSummary2.Visible = false;
                ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                lblPopUpMsg2.Text = msg;
                lblPopUpMsg2.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (location.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    txtMarket.Text = location.Rows[0]["LOC_DESC"].ToString();
                    hdnLocId.Value = location.Rows[0]["LOC_ID"].ToString();
                    //ValidationSummary2.Visible = false;
                    ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                    lblPopUpMsg2.Text = "Please verify Market matches code entered.";
                    lblPopUpMsg2.Visible = true;
                    //return;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtMarket.Text = string.Empty;
                    //ValidationSummary2.Visible = false;
                    ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                    lblPopUpMsg2.Text = "No market was found for the code entered.\n\rPlease check and re-enter the code.";
                    lblPopUpMsg2.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the minimum text to reproduce the issue? Or did you dump all the text of your source files?

Comment: That is all the text in the aspx file but not all the text in the cs file.  I can post all the cs file if needed.

Comment: I found my issue.  Last Pass must not work well with IE.  When I was testing in Chrome, I had no issue, but just IE.  I disabled Last Pass and everything works fine.